# Vuetify.js how to exclude ress.css

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, npm, vuetify.js

Is there any way to exclude ress.css from Vuetify? It overrides Bootstrap and my styles. I tried just to delete in from Vuetify directory in node_modules but it didn't help

Answer (score 1):

You can comment it out in `node_modules/vuetify/src/styles/generic/_index.scss` as follwoing:

```
@import './animations.scss';
@import './colors.scss';
// @import './reset.scss';
@import './elevation.scss';
@import './transitions.scss';
```

But it is an ugly solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known problem in Vuetify. There is a solution proposed by [ZeroThe2nd](https://github.com/ZeroThe2nd) — https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/8530#issuecomment-666992150.

Basically, if you're using webpack, you can utilize a plugin to strip the `reset.sass` from the source code on the compilation step.

It's a workaround, but a much better one than messing up with the lib sources manually.